# What kind of input rasters should I use in a Spatial Analyst Corridor process?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst

I´m trying to map corridors between stands of hardwood. I´ve tried cost path, almost all the time get strange or empty outputs. Now I saw the other tool called Corridor and thought I might give it a shot. But what should I have as inputs? It makes sense to me to use a cost distance raster as one of the inputs but the other? And what does a good output looks like - (so I know if this is the right tool for me)? Tried with the ArcGIS help and online guides but they are very unspecific if you don´t want to go into programming.